# A minor edit to Documentation to add colouring to code, is it correct?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've came across a user who is adding very minor changes to the documentation, that I believe, don't make it any more readable.

They've gone through and added the tag before any code without it. An example would be:

```
interface Command {
    //code here
}
```

Becomes:

```
<!-- language: java -->
interface Command {
    //code here
}
```

The reason they state is:

> Added Java tag, so code gets colored

**EDIT**

The next section is incorrect

---

But they aren't including the bits where it should have `<!-- begin snippet-->`, so the colouring never applies (I believe, though please do correct me if I am wrong).

---

**END OF EDIT**

I consider this edit very trivial and not worth adding to the documentation, unless more information was also added (Which it isn't). Am I correct to believe that, or should we make sure all the code has the correct colouring?

If people want an example, please ask and I can show a few.

Comment: So, you mean there are users who contribute exceedingly simple, no-expertise-required-whatsoever edits in order to farm reputation? I am shocked, really.

Comment: I know, it's surprising really, who'd thought people would do such a thing ^^

Comment: Really, if edit comments in Docs were honest, most of them would read "Made a trivial change, so that I get up to 200 free rep points per day for no effort whatsoever." And can you blame them? This is the kind of contributions, which the current system is incentivizing.

Comment: To clear up a quick comment in your post: To get syntax highlighting (the coloring mentioned in the edit comment), you don't _need_ to have the `<!-- begin snippet -->` comment. That comment is just to turn the code into the HTML/JavaScript/CSS _runnable snippet._ The `<!-- language: java -->` comment just tells the syntax highlighter to highlight the code as _Java_ code.

Answer (score 2):

In questions or answers I frequently apply such revisions, because it's functional to see syntax highlighting.

However, I only do this if the algorithm for default highlighting doesn't pick the right scheme (or none), for instance, when SQL is shown in a post tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

So I'd say: yes it's appropriate where it actually changes the visible syntax highlighting. As long as we don't hear a bell ringing when someone edits for rep harvesting only, we should assume they do it with honorable intentions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll keep that in mind next time I spot it